# How do I dynamically allocate memory for the field of a struct?

Tags: c, struct

I have this hash structure:

```
typedef struct _TD_ {
    int size;       /* the size of the v */
    ALG v;          /* the table elements */
} TD;
```

and a list structure:

```
typedef struct cellista{
    void *info;
    struct cellista *next;
} TcelulaG, *TLG, **ALG;
```

and a structure to which `info` points:

```
typedef struct cuv{
    int frecv;
    char *s;
}word;
```

Somewhere inside the program I want to allocate some memory for the `char *s` like this:

```
TLG aux;
…
((word*)(aux->info))->s=strdup(str);
```

and it gives me a warning "*assigment makes pointer from integer without a cast*...why?

Comment: Works for me: http://ideone.com/YfRHwI. Are you sure that's the code you're compiling? Could you post a complete test case that reproduces the error?

Comment: No need to cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: You should not use names that start with an underscore.  That's the simple rule to remember.  They're reserved for the implementation.  You can simply use `typedef struct TD { … } TD;`  Using pointer-hiding typedefs like `TLG` and `ALG` is widely regarded as a bad idea — doubly so when the type is not opaque.  (It is sort of OK if the client code never uses `.` or `->` in association with the type.  Obviously, the implementation will need to use those operators.)

Comment: TLG aux;what it means

Comment: i tried to use "((word*)(aux->cuvant))->s=strdup(str);" instead but it cracks

Comment: As currently in the question, the compiler doesn't assign memory for the structure TLG (a pointer) is supposed to point to (as in, the compiler only reserves memory for a pointer, not the object pointed to). How this (only) leads to the warning you say you get, I don't understand.

Comment: i tried to use strdup instead(i edited the post ) , but it also gives me seg fault. i tried to use even :
*((word*)(aux->info))->s=strdup(str);
(here str is of type void* , do i have to make a cast to char* inside strdup ? )

Comment: You need to *declare* the structure pointed to, not just a pointer to it. Try this; TcelulaG a; TLG aux = &a, then as before,

Comment: @gnometorule if i want to use &a , i would use ALG which is a double pointer

Comment: &a is a *pointer*, as is TLG, by your definitions (a is the primitive object that you derefence). I'm just using your definitions. Just try it, it should work: you're operating on an object you never defined.

Comment: @gnometorule i did this before "if ((aux = malloc(sizeof(TcelulaG))) == NULL) return 1;Ț and it worked , so i guess i have already memory reserved for aux

Answer (score 1):

You are calling malloc() and you've not declared malloc() by including `<stdlib.h>`. By default, functions are assumed to return an int so you're supposed to declare a function before using it.

Because you have not included `<stdlib.h>`, you are assigning int to a char * which is a pointer. Hence you get the warning "assigment makes pointer from integer without a cast".

Comment: if you mean stdlib.h ofc i included it :)

Comment: But the OP is not using `malloc`, he's using `strdup` which is declared in `string.h`, not int `stdlib.h`.

Comment: that was in the original post @KrzysztofAdamski , but i changed it after he answered :)